# Appending td to rows with $.each loop JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, each

I am trying to add data to table cells via an each loop in JQuery. My code for the loop is below.

```
 $.getJSON(filter, function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, val) {
           var entry = $('<tr>').append(
            $.each(val, function (key, val) {      
                $('<td contenteditable="true">').text(val);
            }));

            // var entry = $('<tr>').append(
            //     $('<td contenteditable="true">').text(val.firstName),
            //     $('<td contenteditable="true">').text(val.lastName),
            //     $('<td contenteditable="true">').text(val.address),
            //     $('<td contenteditable="true">').text(val.city),
            //     $('<td contenteditable="true">').text(val.state),
            //     $('<td contenteditable="true">').text(val.zipcode)
            // );
            entry.appendTo(table);
```

The loop code is not populating the table with the rows. If I run the commented section below the $.each loop instead it populates fine. I can log the value of val in the loop and the data is coming in fine. I can even log to the td
Any ideas on why this is not working will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is because you cannot call `$.each()` from within the `append()` method - at least not in the manner you're attempting to. You need to first append the `tr` elements, then add the `td` to that in the inner loop.

Alternatively you can build the HTML in a single string and call `append()` once, like this:

```js
$.getJSON(filter, function(data) {
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    var tds = val.map(function(value) {
      return ' <td contenteditable="true">' + value + '</td>';
    });
    table.append('<tr>' + tds.join('') + '</tr>');
  });
});
```

Comment: For some reason I am getting a 'val.map is not a function' error. Don't know why I used part of  the below answer using $.map(val, fucntion(){...}) and it worked. I thank you as your answer was helpful in me understanding how $.each works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Each method just iterates, you want to give back the element and for that you use map instead of each :

```
$.map(val, function (key, val) {      
    return $('<td contenteditable="true">').text(val);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`append` can accept a function and will use it's return value. You need to `map` the results within your `append` and return that result.

```
$.each(data, function (key, val) {
    var entry = $('<tr>').append(
        return $.map(val, function (key, val) {      
            return $('<td contenteditable="true">').text(val);
        }));
});
```